# Drupal 7 - Where is the Menu Description stored?

Tags: drupal-7

For the life of me I can't seem to track down where the "Menu Description" value's stored in Drupal 7!

For example:

I added a new menu link called "Cookie" and the menu description called "Yummy". I go into the Drupal database and I can't seem to locate the string "Yummy" in
menu_custom or menu_links or menu_router infact i dumped the database and searched for the string "Yummy" and still can't locate this.

Any help will be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in your `menu_links` table under the options field.  Note that it is not the only data in that field.

Comment: thanks for that. but i meant the “description” for “link_title” in the table “menu_links”. wheres that saved? thanks :)

Comment: @supernoob: sorry, didn't read carefully enough.  I've updated answer above.

Comment: `$links = menu_load_links('insert-menu-name-here');` gets you all the links for a particular menu. `$links[0]['options']['attributes']['title'];` gives you the description for the first menu link of the menu.